# Swift - send header view behind rest of collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, imessage-extension

Ok I have a custom sticker app wherein Im trying to accomplish this effect, the background view behind rest of the cells:

[image]

So far Ive created my background view:

```
self.addSubview(bgView)
        self.sendSubviewToBack(bgView)
```

and tried

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
                        at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        let headerView: HeaderCollectionReusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! HeaderCollectionReusableView

    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(headerView)
```

but the background view still appears on top of the cells. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting effect!

Have you tried:

- Adding a dummy header view
- ... behind a `Container View`
- ... that holds a `Collection view` (with a transparent background)

Example:

> Storyboard

[image: storyboard]

> Result

[image: result]

> Runtime

[image: runtime]

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to move forward with a supplementary view for your background - a more reliable way to achieve the desired behavior is to change [`zIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayoutattributes/1617768-zindex) for `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`. This approach requires `UICollectionViewLayout` subclassing.

For a static background view approach: If background view and collection view have the same superview, background view is below collection view and collection view has a transparent background - your background view will be always below.